# Trying to setup a print server but CUPS won't list connected printer

Tags: raspbian, printing, cups

I am quite new to the world of Raspberry Pi, I got my kit (Raspberry Pi 4 4GB) yesterday evening, so sorry for asking a (maybe) noob question. As a first project, I want to setup a print server. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-print-server

I have a Canon PIXMA MG2470 Inkjet Printer which works fine with both my Mac and PC when physically connected via USB, but I cannot seem to connect it to my Raspberry Pi. After following all the instructions on the tutorial, my printer does not show up under "Local Printers" in Add Printer section of CUPS Administration. The printer is connected and has power, but seems like my Pi won't recognize the printer.

Can anyone kindly help me in this situation of what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: Note that the gutenprint driver for this printer is marked "experimental" and that Cannon does not support drivers on ARM. First step would be to see if the printer gets recognized. Start `sudo tail -f /var/log/messages' and unplug/replug the printer.

Comment: To check for comparability go to, https://openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Canon